# Is there a new version of multilingual APP for VS 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, multilingual-app-toolkit

Is there a newer version of the multilingual app for VS 2019, it shows 2019 in the description but when you install it, there is the below warning :(

[image: Deprecated APIs]

Added link to MS about issue:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/synchronously-autoloaded-extensions?view=vs-2019

Comment: Deprecated means it won't be updated any more and should be removed.

Comment: My thinking in this case was deprecated ment, the package was using deprecated API calls and needed to be upgraded and was wondering if anyone had heard if they were going to.

Comment: I can't find any deprecation announcement, no roadmap or even a recent article. The docs were last updated over a year ago. I suspect the toolkit really is deprecated and replaced by newer Azure/Bing translation APIs or toolkits, but nobody bothered to announce it until they released a VS2019-compatible extension

Comment: I don't think this can be answered here, unless someone knows someone in the relevant teams. It could really be oversight - couldn't the toolkit be modified to use a different service? Or MAT may be about to be replaced by something else that hasn't been announced yet - Build 2019 takes place in less than a month. It's a "bit" of a mess any way you look at it

Answer (score 0):

The Multilingual App Toolkit runs in VS2019. The warning is, I believe, about the fact that the MAT depends on an API in VS2019 that may go away in the future. That would break the tool, if it happened and the author did not fix the dependency.

Answer (score 0):

They responded to my question.

> Hi John,
>
> Today :-)
>
> MAT v4.0.6910.0 implements the PackageAsync model and removes the warning about not working in the future.
>
> Thank you,
> Cameron
>
> https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MultilingualAppToolkit.MultilingualAppToolkit-18308&ssr=false#qna